# How to skip an accordion section if form within section has already been submitted

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion, multipartform-data

I am using the jQuery UI Accordion to include several individual forms. When a user clicks on "continue," the form in that section is submitted, and the next section opens. Users may click an "edit" button to open a previously submitted section and edit that section. Once done, the user clicks on "continue," the form is resubmitted, and the next section opens. I would like to set it up so that the next unsubmitted section opens, rather than just the next section. Any suggestions?

Here's the part of the code I'm currently using to open the next section:

```
$("#applicant-form").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
            $(form).ajaxSubmit({    
...

    complete: function(e) {

   var acc = $("#accordion"),
index = acc.accordion('option','active'),
total = acc.children('div').length,
nxt = index + 1;
    acc.accordion('activate', nxt);
        }   
  });       

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a state attribute to each form containing div whose value would be one of two values: 0 for unsubmitted and 1 for submitted.

Then update your code to:

```
complete: function(e){
  var acc = $('#accordion'),
  index = acc.accordion('option','active'),
  total = acc.children('div').length;

  // Updating state of just submitted form 
  acc.children('div:eq('+index+')').attr('state',1);

  // Finding next unsubmitted form
  acc.children('div').each(function(i){
    if($(this).attr('state') == 0) {
      nxt = i;
      return false;
    }
  })

  acc.accordion('activate',nxt);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not seem to work for me. Now, when I click "continue," the section closes, but the next one doesn't open.

Comment: Sorry about that, I realized I made 2 errors 1. misspelled accordion on line 3 2. Forgot to exit the iterator (by returning false) when the first unsubmitted form is found. Just updated the code to reflect these changes.

Comment: I'm still having trouble with this one. For some reason, a section is completely skipped when I use this code, even though the section has not been submitted yet. Do you know of anything in your code that might be causing this?